# When would I use “once” versus “nonce”?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Looking at the definitions for *once* and *nonce*. they appear very similar to me.

Under what circumstances would one or the other be a more appropriate word choice?

Comment: Nonce is an adjective, once is an adverb

Comment: Nonce probably wouldn't be used in British English

Comment: *Nonce* in BrE slang has a **very** different meaning.

Comment: To emphasise the point made by Andrew Leach: Do NOT use nonce in Australia. Or be ready to duck the punch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Once* and *nonce* aren't similar enough to be interchangeable despite their both meaning "one time". They are also in different registers. Don't use *nonce* unless you want to sound pretentious. The most common uses of that word are in this snippet from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word):

> "A nonce word is a word used only 'for the nonce'....An example of a nonce word in the works of Shakespeare is 'honorificabilitudinitatibus'."

*Nonce word* is a technical term, so it's not pretentious unless you know that your audience doesn't know it. *For the nonce* is easily replaceable with *for the moment*.

Comment: Usage of *for the nonce* has [seriously fallen off](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+nonce&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) over the past century. I think for all practical purposes if you're not already in the habit of using it, you probably don't want to start now. Basically, you missed the boat. But *nonce word* is useful terminology.

Comment: @Fu: Yes, it has seriously fallen off, which is why I said _Don't use "nonce" unless you want to sound pretentious_. I, however, have been using it **for centuries**, if not **for ages**, but only with people who I know understand it. They're always well-read and almost always over 50.

Comment: S'ok. I left us ole farts an out with *already in the habit of using it*. Going with the flow though, I have to say I'm as likely to be using it *facetiously* as "naturally" these days - in fact, it's been that way with me for [yonks](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yonks)

Comment: @Fu: Nice slang term there. It's been yonks since I've read or heard that one. One doesn't hear it much west of the pond.